# getting exception (org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException) when running jgitflow start on my maven package

Tags: bitbucket, jgitflow-maven-plugin

this is the full error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start (default-cli) on project myproject-acls: Error starting release: Error starting release: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:myprojectwebtransformation/myproject-acls.git: Auth fail -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start (default-cli) on project myproject-acls: Error starting release: Error starting release: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:myprojectwebtransformation/myproject-acls.git: Auth fail
```

---

I am using a passwordless SSH key to authenticate between my computer and Bitbucket.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Thanks!

edit1: not sure if it matters but I'm on macos. When creating my ssh key, I've tried rsa, ssh-rsa and rsa-sha2-512.

Comment: We just started having the same issues on some of our Jenkins pipelines that use Fargate Docker Jenkins slave nodes, but still works on the same installation on the EC2 instance tho. I'm also pulling my hair out at this point with this.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne I fixed it/found a workaround by using HTTPS but probably not going to work in your situation as you're using jenkins (haven't really looked if Jenkins can accept username/password as part of the build config). good luck